# Querying all records from one table, add column from another with foreign key constraint

Tags: sql

Apologies for the cryptic title, I don't quite know how to title this question. I'm asking here rather than StackOverflow since I've got a working query, I'm just wondering if it can be improved.

Anyway, I've got three tables, `administration`, `mapping` and `used_mappings`. `Administration` holds details of individual financial administrations, `mapping` is a "static" table holding details for all available financial mappings, `used_mappings` holds records of what mappings are used by what administration (not every administration uses every mapping). The `used_mappings` table also has a column, `custom_name`, so the columns look as follows;

Administration

```
| id | name    |
|----|---------|
| 1  | Admin 1 |
| 2  | Admin 2 |
```

Mapping

```
| id | name      |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | Mapping 1 |
| 2  | Mapping 2 |
| 3  | Mapping 3 |
| 4  | Mapping 4 |
| 5  | Mapping 5 |
```

Used mapping

```
| id | administration_id | mapping_id | custom_name       |
|----|-------------------|------------|-------------------|
| 1  | 1                 | 1          | Revenue           |
| 2  | 1                 | 3          | Cost of sales     |
| 3  | 2                 | 1          | Bar revenue       |
| 4  | 2                 | 3          | Cost of bar sales |
| 5  | 2                 | 4          | Wages             |
```

I now need to fetch all records from `mapping`, regardless of them being used, and where a `custom_name` is defined in `used_mappings` for a specific administration, add it on as an extra column (and have `custom_name` in the results be `null` if no `custom_name` exists.)

I first tried a simple `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT  M.id,
        M.name,
        U.custom_name as customName
FROM    mapping M
LEFT JOIN used_mapping U ON U. = M.id
WHERE U.administration_id = 2;
```

And although it does fetch the correct `custom_name`s, because of the `WHERE U.administration_id = 1;` it only fetches rows from `used_mapping` where that condition is met. In other words, in this example it fetches

```
| id | name         | customName        |
|----|--------------|-------------------|
| 1  | Mapping 1    | Bar revenue       |
| 3  | Mapping 3    | Cost of bar sales |
| 4  | Mapping 4    | Wages             |
```

rather than

```
| id | name      | customName        |
|----|-----------|-------------------|
| 1  | Mapping 1 | Bar revenue       |
| 2  | Mapping 2 | null              |
| 3  | Mapping 3 | Cost of bar sales |
| 4  | Mapping 4 | Wages             |
| 5  | Mapping 5 | null              |
```

I've got it working with a slightly more complex `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT  id,
        name,
        custom_name
    FROM mapping
AS M
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT custom_name,
            mapping_id
    FROM used_mappings
    WHERE administration_id = 2
) AS U ON U.mapping_id = M.id;
```

but it takes twice as long compared to fetching all rows from `mapping` (obviously because for every record in `mapping`, it runs a query on `used_mappings` as well). Hence my question, is there a way of making the query more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  M.id,
        M.name,
        U.custom_name as customName
FROM    mapping M
LEFT JOIN used_mapping U ON U. = M.id
WHERE U.administration_id = 2;
```

The problem is in the `where` statement. Here it checks whether the `administration_id = 2`. For mappings where there is no match in `used_mapping` this id will be `null`. So it gets filtered out. Essentially you're performing an `inner join` here.

Instead you can also allow rows that have `administration_id is null`:

```
SELECT  M.id,
        M.name,
        U.custom_name as customName
FROM    mapping M
LEFT JOIN used_mapping U ON U. = M.id
WHERE U.administration_id = 2 or U.administration_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: The problem is that `U.administration_id` can't be null. `Used_mapping` holds the `mapping`s used by each administration, so if a mapping isn't used by a certain administration, it simply doesn't appear in `used_mapping`.

Comment: @Alex it can't be null in the table, it can be after the left join: rows in `mapping` that don't exist in `used_mapping` (2 and 5), won't have a matching record in the result set after the join, so there the columns coming from the `used_mapping` table will be null. Try executing `select * from mapping M left join used_mapping U on U.mapping_id = M.id`: you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Hmm, oddly your query works in a sample database I quickly set up, with limited records, but doesn't work in the actual database despite the structure being the same.

Comment: @Alex at risk of turning this into a SO-debug session, can you describe how it doesn't work?

Comment: I just realised the error, some mappings are simply not used by any administration ever, so they won't appear when running the query. Your query works in case all records from one column are used in the other, but that's not the case for me sadly. Basically, there's nothing wrong with your query, it's just not usable in my situation